# Can't add JCheckBox to Pane in Java

Tags: java, jcheckbox

I cannot get the JCheckBoxes to work.
I use a normal Pane, no layout. Buttons, Labels, TextFields and comboboxes all seem to be working just fine, except for the JCheckBoxes.
My code looks somewhat like this:

```
Pane root = new Pane();

Button btn = new Button();
JCheckBox voer = new JCheckBox("Voerbakjes");

btn.setLayoutX(50);
btn.setLayoutY(600);
voer.setLayoutX(300);
voer.setLayoutY(300);

root.getChildren().add(voer);
root.getChildren().add(btn);
```

The button is working, and also it's setLayout functions. These also don't seem to work on the JCheckBox. Is there some way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You're creating a JCheckBox. All "J" prefixed components imports the swing components, as your button, label and panel are AWT UI.

For this to works use all J components.

```
JPanel root = new JPanel();

JButton btn = new JButton();
JCheckBox voer = new JCheckBox("Voerbakjes");

btn.setLayoutX(50);
btn.setLayoutY(600);
voer.setLayoutX(300);
voer.setLayoutY(300);

root.getChildren().add(voer);
root.getChildren().add(btn);
```

Comment: Spelling! Sure it is not Add

Comment: It just keeps saying that it cannot find symbol when I try that

Comment: Try creating a JPanel instead of a pane.

Comment: How do I add the button and the others on a JPanel?

Comment: Works the same way as the pane.

Comment: Nope, it will whine about my button, label etc now, but the checkbox works

Comment: Oh, my bad. You have to create a JButton and JLabel as well. Should wokr properly.